# Comparing Dates in Google Sheets with different format

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried everything and can't make this work.

File 1 has a date and transactions.
File 2 has date and other exported date from a software, so Column A is a date that is not formatted.

Basically I want to get the number of transactions per day on file 1, when in file 2 we have Column B with "google / cpc" and Column C contains "search".

The problem here is that I can't make the dates from File 1 to File 2 to compare to give me the transactions. It never compares.

File 1 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xvoo2Rob3kI4duPpmCTfhMLPlvdzIJY9ZQBV7CHccoc/edit?usp=sharing

File 2 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Enq805we6_XcTkytwfj6ON1ZnITnAGUwLVoaGzXeco/edit?usp=sharing

I tried to make the date from file 2 like the date from file 1 using concatenate and LEFT and RIGHT formulas, but they look similar to the eye, but google sheets can't compare.
I tried to also change the format to date and play with it, but still can't get them to compare the dates.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Using your current formula,try changing your values with text and back to number with value:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(VALUE(TEXT(A3:A33,"yyyymmdd")), QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("10Enq805we6_XcTkytwfj6ON1ZnITnAGUwLVoaGzXeco", "Sheet2!A:N"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col6) where Col2 = 'google / cpc' and Col3 = 'search' group by Col1"), 2, 0)))
```

Comment: It looks fine, but it doesn't search for column C that contains the keyword "search" on File 2

Comment: Updated with that condition

Answer (score 0):

you can try this out:

```
=MAKEARRAY(31,1,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(LAMBDA(z,SUM(IFNA(FILTER(INDEX(z,,6),INDEX(DATE(LEFT(INDEX(z,,1),4),MID(INDEX(z,,1),5,2),RIGHT(INDEX(z,,1),2)))=INDEX(A3:A33,r),INDEX(z,,2)="google / cpc",REGEXMATCH(INDEX(z,,3),"(?i)search")))))(importrange("10Enq805we6_XcTkytwfj6ON1ZnITnAGUwLVoaGzXeco","Sheet2!A:F")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

> they look similar to the eye, but google sheets can't compare

The values like `20230102` in spreadsheet `2` column `A` look like dates but are actually numbers in the neighborhood of 20 million, such as `20,230,102`.

It is unclear whether your intention is to use that data in just this one report or several such reports. If the latter, you may want to **Insert > Sheet** in spreadsheet `1` and put this formula in cell `A1` of that new 'Import' sheet to import and convert the data:

```
=arrayformula( 
  lambda( 
    ssId, datelikeRangeA1, criteriaRangeA1, transactionsRangeA1, 
    lambda( 
      dates, criteria, transactions, 
      query( 
        { dates, criteria, transactions }, 
        "select Col1, sum(Col3) where Col2 = 'google / cpc' group by Col1 
         label Col1 'Date', sum(Col3) 'Total transactions' ", 
        0 
      ) 
    )( 
      to_date( value( regexreplace( 
        to_text( importrange(ssId, datelikeRangeA1) ), 
        "(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})", "$1-$2-$3" 
      ) ) ), 
      importrange(ssId, criteriaRangeA1), 
      importrange(ssId, transactionsRangeA1)  
    ) 
  )( 
    "10Enq805we6_XcTkytwfj6ON1ZnITnAGUwLVoaGzXeco", 
    "Sheet2!A2:A", 
    "Sheet2!B2:B", 
    "Sheet2!F2:F" 
  ) 
)
```

The formula may look a bit complex, but it is easy to adjust to other similar imports you may need by modifying the parameters at the end. You can then more easily to refer to the data in your various reports. To match the dates in `Sheet1!A3:A33`, put this formula in cell `Sheet1!B3`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifna( 
    vlookup( 
      A3:A33, 
      Import!A2:B, 
      columns(Import!A2:B), 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```